# getting rintime error on this it is basic

Tags: c++, runtime-error

why am i geting runtime error in one

thats my question i am writing this simply because it is showing to lksdjflksjflkjsdflk

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    long int L;
    long int l;
    cin>>L;
    cin>>l;
    long int ans=L%l;
    if(L>=l)
    {
        cout<<ans;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<L;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What runtime error did you get?

Comment: You code is not checking the input for errors.  So... *garbage in, garbage out*.

Comment: Most likely, you are getting a runtime error because `l == 0`, and then your program divides by zero.

Comment: can u plz suggest an edit plz

Comment: You still have not posted the runtime error. That would be my second suggestion to edit the question. My first suggestion would be to remove the ***thats my question i am writing this simply because it is showing to lksdjflksjflkjsdflk*** line of your question.

Comment: bro this is a question on website it says only runtime error for some test case

Comment: I agree that @IgorTandetnik probably guessed the reason for the runtime error. You can avoid using % if l is 0.

Comment: Normally when you get a runtime error in a debugger you get some type of text message describing the nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide the inputs for L,l and runtime error description... It's ambiguous and we have to guess.. hope you are not passing 0 to 'l'..